# Read a single sector from a disk

Tags: linux, io, kernel

I am trying to read a single specific sector from the disk directly. I've currently run out of ideas and any suggestions how to go about it would be great!

Comment: you would use dd for this, or you could write a c program and use the write sys call.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this to do it from the CLI:

```
# df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              27G   24G  1.6G  94% /
# dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda2 of=/tmp/sector200 skip=200 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
```

From `man 4 sd`:

```
FILES
   /dev/sd[a-h]: the whole device
   /dev/sd[a-h][0-8]: individual block partitions
```

And if you want to do this from within a program, just use a combination of system calls from `man 2 ...` like `open, lseek,`, and `read`, with the parameters from the `dd` example.

Comment: Given the sizes of disks these days, either use `lseek64()`, or `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` to ensure that `off_t` is a 64 bit type.

Comment: could you please give some c programming language specific functions to read and write to disk sectors?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the best programmatic approach is, but from the Linux command-line you could use the dd command in combination with the raw device for your disk to directly read from the disk.

You need to sudo this command to get access to the raw disk device (e.g. /dev/rdisk0).

For example, the following will read a single 512-byte block from an offset of 900 blocks from the top of disk0 and output it to stdout.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk0 bs=512 skip=900 count=1
```

See the dd man page to get additional information on the parameters to dd.

Comment: Disc devices are not normally called /dev/rdisk0 under Linux, you probably want something like /dev/sda

Comment: does skip/seek get me to a physical sector or logical block?

Comment: This didn't actually print anything on the screen for me, until I piped it into hexdump, e.g. `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 skip=900 count=1 | hexdump -C`

Answer (score 2):

In C it is something like the following... It would require root permissions. I think you need to open the file with O_DIRECT if you want to read single sectors. Otherwise you'll get a page.  I'm not sure if the aligned buffer is required for a read, but it is for a write.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SECTOR_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int offset = 0;
    int length = 5;
    int rc = -1;

    char *sector = aligned_alloc(SECTOR_SIZE, SECTOR_SIZE);
    memset(sector, 0, SECTOR_SIZE);
    /* replace XXX with the source block device */
    int fd=open("/dev/XXX", O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);

    lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        rc = read(fd, sector, SECTOR_SIZE);
        if (rc < 0)
            printf("sector read error at offset = %d + %d\n %s", offset, i, strerror(errno));
        printf("Sector: %d\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < SECTOR_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%x", sector[i]);
            if ((j + 1) % 16 == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(sector);
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `hdparm`

For instance-

```sh
hdparm --read-sector 16782858 /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

The other folks have pretty much covered it. You need to

- access to the disk's device file (either be root or, better, change the permissions on it)
- use the file IO functions to read sectors = chunks of (usually) 512 bytes from said disk.

Comment: could you please mentions some specific c programming language functions to read and write on sectors