# Reading a specific sector from a hard drive using C on Linux (GNU/Linux )

Tags: c, linux

I know that a hard drive are system's **files** (**/dev/sdXX**) –then treated like files-, I have questions about this:

1. I tried those following lines of code but nothing positive

-------first attempt----------

```
int numSecteur=2;
char secteur [512];
FILE* disqueF=fopen("/dev/sda","r"); //tried "rb" and sda1 ...every thing
fseek(disqueF, numSecteur*512,SEEK_SET);
fread(secteur, 512, 1, disqueF);
fclose(disqueF);
```

-------Second attempt----------

```
    int i=open("/dev/sda1",O_RDONLY);
    lseek(i, 0, SEEK_SET);
    read(i,secteur,512);
    close(i);
```

------printing the results----------

```
printf("hex : %04x\n",secteur);
printf("string : %s\n",secteur);
```

2. Why the size is of the file /dev/sda1 is just 8 KBytes ?

[image: the size !!!]

3. How the data is stored (binary or hex….) "for the printing"

Please, I need some clues, and if someone need more details just he ask.

Thanks a lot.

**Ps: Running kali 2 64bits ”debian” on VMware** and i am RooT.

Comment: Nothing works? `printf("hex : %04x\n",secteur);` is undefined behaviour passing a pointer to `unsigned int`. Then `printf("string : %s\n",secteur);` will only produce meaningful output from a nul-terminated printable character array. Finally your code is devoid on any of the essential error checking usually performed on I/O functions.

Comment: *"How the data is stored (binary or hex….)"* -- Magnetic particles only have two states or orientations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a single sector from a disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1753067/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot printf() array of chat like that, you need right print result. For example as hex dump:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(secteur); i++) {
    printf ("%02x ", secteur[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0)
        printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: plz, two more questions :          1) why when i use `strlen(secteur)` it does not return 512 ?               2) why when I print the content of **sda** it is like this (it is normal when i tried on sda1 ..) ? ![pct "like this"](https://s10.postimg.org/5855ov0ah/qsdfqfdsf.png).

Comment: 1. No. strlen() is for strings. In C strings is array with 0(zero) in the end. Lets say `char str[] = "abc";` same as `char str[] = {'a','b','c',0};` strlen() function just search for first 0 in array, and return index + 1.

Comment: 2. Try `printf ("%02ux ", secteur[i]);`. In printf format string '%02ux'. '02' mean 'zero padded to 2 digit' (if you print '5' it will output '05'). 'u' mean 'unsigned'. 'x' mean 'hex representation of digit'

Comment: for 2) still the same problem, just with **sda** (it is normal with sda1 and sda5...) , and  `printf ("%02ux ", secteur[i])` it gives me an additional x at the end of each two digits .

Comment: thanks Mr @komar , solved with `unsigned char secteur [512];`

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I tried those following lines of code but nothing positive

That's not a question.

> 2. Why the size is of the file /dev/sda1 is just 8 KBytes ?

That isn't the file size, it's the device number. (There are two parts, so the device number of sda1 is 8,1)

> 3. How the data is stored (binary or hex….) "for the printing"

Data isn't "stored for the printing". Data is stored (in electrical voltages representing binary, but you don't need to know that), and you can print it any way you want.

Comment: *"Data is stored (in electrical voltages representing binary"* -- HDDs store data in magnetic domains, and the magnetic flux is used to generate the binary values.  You would need batteries to store electrical energy as "voltages".

Comment: @sawdust DRAM uses capacitors. And I assume "for the printing" means between the point where you read it from disk and the point where you print it, when it is in RAM. (SRAM also uses voltages but not capacitors)